# I have tried try all the answers on stackoverflow,but failed

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, servlets

**The absolute uri: http//:java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**
When I run the SpringMVC web application using Tomcat7.0, the browser give me this error,
please give me some advice to solve this problem，I would appreciate that you could tell me how do deal with it.

**Here is my POM.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.6</version>
           <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
```

**Here is the JSP code**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http//:java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <html>
    <head><title>Spring3.0xLogin</title></head>
    <body>
        <c:if test="${!empty error}">
            <font color="red"><c:out value="${error}"/></font>
        </c:if>
        <form action="<c:url value="/loginCheck.html"/>" method="post">
            User：<input type="text" name="userName"><br>
            PassWord：<input type="passWord"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
```

You put colon after slashes. Write this

Comment: please describe in details

Comment: please describe in details

Comment: You just write wrong URI format  after protocol(http) should be :// but You write //:

Comment: @ZackZhang What details? Copy that string.

Comment: You have some eagle eyes my friend.. :D, noticing that colon... :-)